# Counter to repeated data in Java

Tags: java

I have a problem with java. In resume, it would be to show a list of users by name (extracted from a .json file), but I must add a suffix 00 to all of them, thus leaving: 'name+00'. In this way, if there are 2 users with the same name then the program should differentiate them by increasing the suffix. For example, if two users are called 'John', the name should look like this: 'John00' and 'John01'.

This is a summary of what I have done:

**Class User:**

```
public class User{

    private String name;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**Class Data:**

```
private HashMap<String, List<User>> readUsers() {
    HashMap<String, List<User>> usuarios= new HashMap<>();

    SimpleFeatureCollection collection = datastore.getFeatureCollection();

    try (SimpleFeatureIterator itrusuarios = collection.features()) {

        int contador=0;
        while (itrusuarios.hasNext()) {

            SimpleFeature simpleFeature = itrusuarios.next();
            User usuario = new User();

           usuario.setName(simpleFeature.getID()+contador); //This don't work
            contador++;

            System.out.println(usuario.getName);
        }

    } finally {
        datastore.dispose();
    }


    return usuarios;
}
```

If I try to add the counter to the name of the user (in the Data class), it does not work as it should, since it shows me the entire list of users, and it adds a number that self-increases: Rose1, John2, John3, Dan4, Anna5...

If I modify the setter of the User class with a counter: `this.name = name+counter`; then it looks like this: Rose0, John0, John0, Dan0, Anna0...

The output I am looking for would be:

> Rose00, John00, John01, Dan00, Anna00...

That is, when you find the same name, only increase that name.

Thank you!

Comment: I fail to understand your strategy. Your method create a HashMap, but never does anything with it, and finally returns it (empty). Before diving into the code, what would be your strategyto implement this?

Comment: I second what @JBNizet said. Overall, it seems you are storing a single counter but you need to store a counter for every _n_ where _n_ = number of _unique_ names. For this I would use a hash map of name to counter.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your map to `Map<String, Integer>`. You will essentially have a map of counters that are accessed by name.

When you request to create a new user, you check the map to see what the current counter value is set to. You increment the associated name-key it every time you run into a name.

There is no need to store a map of name to a list of Users, because there would be no point of "ID-ing" (identifying) them by an ever-increasing value.

**tl;dr:** Just use an name occurrence map that increments based on their appearance.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class NameGenerator {
    private static Map<String, Integer> nameOccuranceMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

        for (String name : Arrays.asList("Rose", "John", "John", "Dan", "Anna")) {
            if (nameOccuranceMap.containsKey(name)) {
                nameOccuranceMap.put(name, nameOccuranceMap.get(name) + 1);
            } else {
                nameOccuranceMap.put(name, 0);
            }
            users.add(new User(String.format("%02d%s", nameOccuranceMap.get(name), name)));
        }

        System.out.println(users.stream().map(User::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
    }

    private static class User {
        private String name;
        public String getName() { return name; }
        public User(String name) { this.name = name; }
        @Override public String toString() { return String.format("User [name=%s]", name); }
    }
}
```

**Output:** `00Rose, 00John, 01John, 00Dan, 00Anna`